# e.pageX and e.pageY differs in IE compared to Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have just opened the link below

http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/

in IE, Chrome and Firefox. Firefox and Chrome provides the same output but the values of pageX and pageY are different in IE.

**Why is it so? Document scroll value isn't affected in IE.**

Comment: Looks as though IE outputs full numbers while chrome is rounding. Interesting.

Comment: for a time, IE can be better maybe ;p... So if it's a round number, try to round it to get the same value !

Comment: just use `parseInt(e.pageX)` and it'll all look the same! or `Math.round(e.pageX)` ... :-P

Comment: Strange. I can't see any obvious rounding or calculations in the jQuery code. It's also strange that the fraction part doesn't change frequently as you move. My best guess is that IE is returning a very small value for some of the legacy page/element offsets. In practice, it probably won't matter because it'll be rounded when you apply it somewhere.